# Firebird: O que fazer quando um framework utiliza alguma palavra reservada?

Tags: firebird

estou com um problema na criação do banco de dados na utilização do Adianti com Firebird 2.1, pois as palavras PASSWORD E ACTIVE são reservadas do Firebird e não consigo seta-las como um atributo. O que posso fazer para resolver essa situação? Lembrando que alterando os campos ACTIVE E PASSWORD a tabela é gerada, porém o sistema não funciona! A seguir está o SQL de criação da tabela!

```
CREATE TABLE system_user (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name varchar(100),
    login varchar(100),
    password varchar(100), <--------------------------- **OS ERROS OCORREM AQUI**
    email varchar(100),
    frontpage_id INTEGER REFERENCES system_program(id),
    system_unit_id INTEGER references system_unit(id),
    active char(1) <----------------------------------- **OS ERROS OCORREM AQUI**
);
```

Comment: A resposta ideal seria o óbvio. Não usar palavras reservadas.

Comment: Tente colocar entre aspas o nome da coluna, como por exemplo "password"

Comment: Agradeço todos pelas respostas, ajudou muito. Essa pergunta teve um nível baixo, espero que me desculpem por algo. Sou novo aqui no stackoverflow e estou aprendendo a cada dia.
Talvez o pessoal tenha entendido errado, mas essa tabela `system_user` é criada pelo adianti framework. Houve palavras reservadas porque estava usando Firebird 2.1 e se mudasse o atributo resultaria em mal funcionamento no Framework. Me foi sugerido alterar o framework para adaptar ao banco (o que seria um pouco trabalhoso), então abandonei o projeto e comecei utilizar o Django, pois a base de dados não iria mudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o ideal é não utilizar palavras reservadas, porém às vezes existem situações especiais que precisamos utilizar tais palavras.

Nestes casos você deve nomear o campo(nome da coluna) entre aspas "*campo*".

Considerando o exemplo passado, seu SQL ficaria assim:

`CREATE TABLE system_user (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name varchar(100),
    login varchar(100),
    "password" varchar(100), 
    email varchar(100),
    frontpage_id INTEGER REFERENCES system_program(id),
    system_unit_id INTEGER references system_unit(id),
    "active" char(1)
);`

Qualquer dúvida estou por aqui.